# Python POST via REST API error JSONArray cannot be cast to JSONObject

Tags: python, json, api, rest, csv

I am trying to create a python script that does the following:

- Parse a CSV file
- Send the CSV file to a remote server via REST API

The code I have is working to parse the CSV file and convert it to a JSON object.

However, when it imports to the remote server, an error message is returned: `org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject`

I think this might be because my code is creating an array of objects rather than a JSON object. How can I solve the issue so that my script will upload the CSV data and properly map the columns and values to the remote table?

```
#Requests package for python import requests
import csv
import json
import requests

f = open('example_import_csv.csv', 'rU')
reader = csv.DictReader(f, fieldnames = ("u_date","u_product","u_serial_number"))
out = json.dumps([row for row in reader])
print(out) 

#Set request parameters
url = 'xxxxxx'
user = 'xxxxxx'
pwd = 'xxxxxxxx'

#Set proper headers
headers = {"Content-Type":"application/json","Accept":"application/json"}

response = requests.post(url, auth=(user, pwd), headers=headers ,data=out)

#Check for HTTP codes other than 200
if response.status_code != 200:
    print('Status:', response.status_code, 'Headers:', response.headers, 'Response Text', response.text, 'Error Response:',response.json())
    exit()

#Decode the JSON response into a dictionary and use the data
print('Status:',response.status_code,'Headers:',response.headers,'Response:',response.json())
```

OUTPUT

```
[{"u_date": "u_date", "u_product": "u_product", "u_serial_number": "u_serial_number"}, {"u_date": "1/12/15", "u_product": "Apples", "u_serial_number": "11"}, {"u_date": "1/29/15", "u_product": "Pears", "u_serial_number": "12"}, {"u_date": "1/12/15", "u_product": "Oranges", "u_serial_number": "13"}, {"u_date": "1/29/15", "u_product": "Blackberries", "u_serial_number": "14"}, {"u_date": "2/5/15", "u_product": "Blueberries", "u_serial_number": "15"}, {"u_date": "2/7/15", "u_product": "Bananas", "u_serial_number": "16"}, {"u_date": "2/7/15", "u_product": "Strawberries", "u_serial_number": "17"}]

Status: 200 Headers: {'Strict-Transport-Security': 'max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains;','Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'}
Response: {'reason': None, 'error': 'org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.simple.JSONObject'}
```

EDIT:

The request must be a JSON object. I need the format to be a JSON object containing a single array.

I tested by manually creating a json object in this format and it works. How can I parse the CSV file to get it into this particular format?

```
{"records":[{"u_date": "u_date", "u_product": "u_product", "u_serial_number": "u_serial_number"}, {"u_date": "1/12/15", "u_product": "Apples", "u_serial_number": "11"}, {"u_date": "1/29/15", "u_product": "Pears", "u_serial_number": "12"}, {"u_date": "1/12/15", "u_product": "Oranges", "u_serial_number": "13"}, {"u_date": "1/29/15", "u_product": "Blackberries", "u_serial_number": "14"}, {"u_date": "2/5/15", "u_product": "Blueberries", "u_serial_number": "15"}, {"u_date": "2/7/15", "u_product": "Bananas", "u_serial_number": "16"}, {"u_date": "2/7/15", "u_product": "Strawberries", "u_serial_number": "17"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your array in a suitable dict:

```
out = json.dumps({'records': [row for row in reader]})
```

You could also leave the encoding to `requests` by passing the object to be encoded [as `json` parameter](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) instead of `data`:

```
out = {'records': [row for row in reader]}
requests.post(url, json=out, ...)
```

In this case requests will also automatically set the content type header to `application/json`, so you don't have to do that manually.